# wpdb insert with no ID

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm new in WordPress
I'm trying to insert on database without knowing the id, here what I'm trying to do:

```
$create = $wpdb->insert('wp_ito_plan', array('name' => $_POST['name'], 'tickets' => $_POST['tickets'], 'price' => $_POST['price'], 'visits' => $_POST['visits']));
```

and I got this error:

```
WordPress database error: [Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY']
INSERT INTO `wp_ito_plan` (`name`,`tickets`,`price`,`visits`) VALUES ('asd','123','123','123')
```

I tried adding to the array: `'id' => $wpdb->insert_id`, but stills the same.

How can I fix this? Do I need to check what is the last ID on database and then increment? There's no easiest way?

Comment: Is the primary key field set to `auto_increment`? If not, it'll default to 0 or whatever on inserts, and your SECOND insert will also get `0` as the id. $wpbd->insert_id will only be available AFTER a successful insert. It's MySQL generating that insert_id, not wordpress.

Comment: Share your table schema please. Is it an `AUTO INCREMENT` column?

Comment: exactly that! I forgot of the AUTO_INCREMENT when I create the table. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though you aren't auto incrementing the ID column so you're insert is going to overwrite an existing row. Set the ID column to auto increment and it should work fine.